# Create a model window for comment in javascript

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I created a comment button.
I want that when the user click on the button a model window will open. The model window should contain a keyboard for writing the comment.

Comment: What have you tried yourself already to achieve this? Can you show us some code?

Comment: I used a comment-toggle, but i decided to change the functionality to a model window. The problem that i haven't work with it until now.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you a little bit. We can't code an entire keyboard for you.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Show the keyboard!"> <!-- the button -->
<div id="wrapper"> <!-- the keyboard -->
<!-- type your code here, make sure that it's css is like the textarea below, display:none;. Then copy-paste the jquery line which says 'textarea', and change 'textarea' to whatever element you added. -->
<textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:30px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    width:400px;
    height:0px;
}

textarea {
    display:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:200px;
    height:160px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input').click(function() { // when the button is clicked...
        $('#wrapper').animate({ height: '+=200px'},100);
        // ...increase the height of the wrapper by 200px
        $('textarea').css({ 'display': 'block'});
        // ...make sure that the textarea is visible
   })
});
```

Link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/16fuhf6r/3/
Comments with code explanation are included.